# Array indexes displaying strange behavior

Tags: c++

I'm trying to create a function that displays an array's contents.

```
void show(string arr[]){
    for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]); i++){
        cout << arr[i] << endl;
    }
}
```

If I replace `sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0])` with the length of the array I'm inputting into the function it works. Which confuses me since `sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0])` evaluates to the length of the array.

Why is this happening?

Here's the calling code if it's relevant.

```
int main()
{
    string arr[] = {"word", "word", "word", "word", "word"};
    show(arr);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In function arguments, `T arr[]` is _identical_ to `T * arr`. You lose size information. So pass the size as argument, or as a template parameter.

Comment: `sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0])` doesn't do what you think it does. Array lenghts aren't kept with the arrays, unless you specify a constant size.

Comment: Use `std::vector`.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Yes it does — just not with pointers.

Comment: @Dúthomhas mentioned the exception.